# Conflicts on using JQuery DatePicker in a web widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, widget

I recently develop a web widget which shows 2 autocomplete components and 2 datepickers, basically is a search bus widget, where you select origin, destination, departure and return date. On some pages the widget works great. But in anothers, the datepicker is having some troubles, most precisely, isn't showing the calendar. Trying wrapping the datepickers to isolate my calendars and not interfering on another scripts/styles/mumbojumbo happening on those websites.

I based my widget on the examples of Alex Mandaron
http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/ and for loading jquery UI components http://alexmarandon.com/articles/widget-jquery-plugins/

But recently I came across on this topic which help me 
[Loading jQuery UI with getScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389404/loading-jquery-ui-with-getscript/4413873#4413873) which is great

But still it doens't work

For more examples, you can check the working widget on
widget-doc.pinbus.com

and here is where isn't working http://www3.pasajes.co/ and select the "Bus" tab and try to click on the "Fecha de Salida" input

Thanks to all!

Comment: You have a javascript error in your page, you should fix that first.

Comment: @simey.me do you mean on www3.pasajes.co? I don't have any access to that page actually. That's why I'm asking about this. The errors you see on that page are from some code of that page.